# Lua calling a methode on instance error attempt to call method 'getCategory' (a nil value)

Tags: class, lua, instance

first of all i am totaly new to LUA so i dont know the right term so sorry for that.
Now to my problem.
I got a class which has a methode `getCategory`. The code of this class is closed source so i cant check its code nor provide it to you. The funny thing is i am able to call `ThisClass:getCategory(instance)` but not `instance:getCategory()` while instance ist created with `instance = ThisClass:new(param)`

Is there any possible solution without the sourcecode of ThisClass?

Thanks for your help.

Julius

Comment: `ThisClass:getCategory(instance)` passes ThisClass AND instance as second arg. Are you sure this worked? Maybe your instance simply has no `getCategory`, are you sure it should have it?

Comment: Probably in this implementation of OOP objects do not have metatables, only classes do.  It is strange, but possible.  What does `getmetatable(instance)` return?

Comment: With no information on the libraries in question we can hardly help.

Comment: the metatable seems to be correct. When i print it all methodes are correct and `getCategory
Type: function`
is part of it.